# Is it possible to bind a WPF control to multiple data contexts?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I've written an UserControl whose DataContext contains a collection and an bool property. The collection is being displayed (and editited) within a data grid, which has custrom column templates. The DataContext of a control in a column is of course an item of the collection of the UserControl's DataContext. However I need to bind one property of the control in a column to the bool property of the UserControl's DataContext and not to the collection item.

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?

Best Regards, Oliver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pulling this straight from my answer on another post

[Getting at the "parent" of a databound object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189753/getting-at-the-parent-of-a-databound-object/1190234#1190234)

Here's the code from the post that I think might pertain to what youre trying to do:

```
<ListBox Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=DataContext.Values}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Basically the DataContext of the ListBox in this case contains a few lists and a combobox within the DataTemplate of the ItemTemplate is bound to a different member of the DataContext of the ListBox while the ItemsSource is bound to the Items member of DataContext.  I would think this could apply to your DataGrid and column templates.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1. Create a custom class which contains the collection and a bool property and set the DataContext to an instance of that class.

Solution 2. Set the user control's DataContext to the collection and add a bool property to your user control.

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataContextDemo.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="self">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=MyBoolProp, ElementName=self}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace DataContextDemo
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool MyBoolProp
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(MyBoolPropProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyBoolPropProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyBoolPropProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyBoolProp", 
                                        typeof(bool), 
                                        typeof(UserControl1), 
                                        new UIPropertyMetadata(true));
    }
}
```